# confusion regarding the optimal solution in rod cutting

Tags: dynamic-programming

I am talking about the famous rod cutting problem in CLRS. 
Two optimal equations are given:

1: r[n] = max(p_n, r_1+r_{n-1}, ..., r_{n-1} + r_1);

2: r[n] = max(p_i+r_{n-1}, ..., p_{n-1} + r_1);

I have been confused for a while regarding why the 2nd equation is correct.

Suppose p_k+r_{n-k} is the max value, is that possible there exists a r_k:
r_k+r_{n-k} > p_k+r_{n-k}?

In such a case, the above 2nd equation is not correct.

Any  help?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know, how to answer it properly. I too had the same confusion so I searched for the same, finally got here. I dont see any answers, so i think either we are too dumb or none has understood the solution properly. How ever I came across the link.[confusion about rod cutting algorithm - dynamic programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666455/confusion-about-rod-cutting-algorithm-dynamic-programming?rq=1). The second explanation here makes some sense to me.
What he says is, For any of the possible solution, it will always be the case that the max contains some Pi which is given in the array. So what we do is, directly include it in our solution. In the recurrence 1: r[n] = max(p_n, r_1+r_{n-1}, ..., r_{n-1} + r_1); the solution might lie in r2+r(n-2) but in the 2nd recurrence the same solution might lie in p1+r(n-1). Let me know if find out any clear answer.