# confusion about rod cutting algorithm - dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I recently saw a rod cutting problem, where B(i) = optimal price for cutting a rod of length i units and p(i) = price of a rod of length i units.

The algorithm given is something like this:
B(i) = max(1<=k<=i) {p(k) + B(i-k)}

Shouldn't it be something like this:
B(i) = max(1<=k<=floor(i/2)) {B(k) + B(i-k)}
where B(1) = p(1);

so that both parts 've the optimal cost instead of cost for a single rod for one part and optimal cost for the second part.

```
for example: B(4) = max{ (B(1) + B(3)); (B(2) + B(2)) }

instead of max{ (p(1) + B(3)); (p(2) + B(2)); (p(3) + B(1)) }
```

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: It isn't clear what the relationship between p & B are (semantically, not mathematically), but the original algorithm seems to assume p is provided and not determined from B.  As your proposal ignores p completely, I'm guessing it doesn't produce the same result.

Comment: @Scott Hunter yeah, p is given which is cost of rod of some length

Answer (score 3):

Actually the formula is correct. You have B(i) = max(1<=k<=i) {p(k) + B(i-k)}. Let's assume you have a rope of length `i`. If you are to cut it then you will cut a piece of length `k` where k is between `1` and `i` and will go on cutting the remaining part of the rope. So overall it costs you  p(k)(price to cut the initial part that you decided you will not cut anymore) and the price to cut the remaining `B(i-k)`. This is precisely what the formula does.

Your solution will also do the job but it has a slight drawback - the solution for each subproblem depends on the solution of two(instead of one) simpler subproblems. I believe because of that it will perform worse on the average. Of course having a subproblem depend on several simpler problems is not forbidden or wrong.

Comment: my doubt is that wont optimal cost involve optimal cost of cutting both parts, instead of leaving one part as it is?

Comment: Nope. No matter how you cut the rope you can assume you cut a part that won't be cut anymore. Without loss of generality you can assume it is the first part being cut.

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume that the optimal price of the rod of length `i` will be obtained by cutting the rod into `p` parts of length `l1, l2, .., lp`  such that `i= l1+ l2 +..+ lp` and `l1<l2<l3<…<lp` (for simplicity).

There exists a rod piece of length `l1` in the optimal solution means that if the rod piece of length  `l1` is further broken into smaller pieces, then the price of the rod piece of length `l1` will decrease. Hence for a rod piece of length `l1`, we can say that `b[l1] = p[l1]`. Similarly we have established, `b[l2] = p[l2], b[l3]= p[l3], ….., b[lp]= p[lp]. =>  b(i) = b(l1) + b(l2) +..+ b(lp)` is optimal………………..Condition 1

Now consider the case of rod of length `l1+l2`. The claim is `b(l1+l2) = b(l1) + b(l2)` is optimal. Let us assume it is not the case. There exists an `L` such that `b(l1+l2) = b(L) + b(l1+l2-L)` is optimal. It means that there exists rods of length `L` and `(l1+l2-L)` such that:

- `b(L) + b(l1+l2-L)>b(l1)+b(l2).`
- =>   `b(l1) + b(l2) + b(l3) +..+ b(lp) < b(L) + b(l1+l2-L) +b(l3) +…+ b(lp)`.
- =>   Which is a contradiction { See Condition 1}
- =>   `b(l1+l2) = b(l1) + b(l2)` is optimal
- =>   Similarly `b(l2+l3+l4) = b(l2) + b(l3) + b(l4)` is optimal and so on.

Now we have a recurrence `b(i) = b(k) + b(i-k) for 1<=k<i`.

- For `k=l1, b(i) = b(l1) + b(i-l1) = p[l1] + b(i-l1)`.
- For `k=l1+l2, b(i) = b(l1+l2) + b(i-l1-l2)`

  - `= b(l1+l2) + b(l3 + l4 +…+lp)`
  - `= [b(l1) + b(l2)] + b(l3 + l4 +…+lp)`
  - `= b(l1) + [b(l2) + b(l3 + l4 +…+lp)]`
  - `= b(l1) + b(l2+l3+l4+…+lp)`
  - `= b(l1) + b(i-l1)`
  - `= p[l1] + b(i-l1)`
- Or for `k= l1+l2, b(i) = p[k’] + b(i-k’)` where `k’=l1`.

So to conclude, if we want to find optimal solution of a rod of length `i`, we try to break the rod of length `i` into 2 parts of length `(l1+l2)` and `(i-l1+l2)` and then we recursively find optimal solutions of the two rod pieces, we end up finding an optimal rod piece of length `l1` and optimal solution of rod of length `i-l1`. Thus we can say:

`b(i) = b(k) + b(i-k ) = p[k’] + b(i-k’) for 1<=k,k’<i.`

Comment: I understand this mathematically but I still can't understand intuitively why when we divide the rod in 2 segments, one part is the normal price and the other the optimal one.. Again, the mathematical proof makes sense but it doesn't seem correct if I think about it

Answer (score 1):

The formula is correct. I think the confusion arises when we think of both formulas to be replacement of the other.
Though they count the same phenomena, it is done in two different ways:

Let, B(i) = optimal price for cutting a rod of length i units and 
     p(i) = price of a rod of length i units.

Formula 1: B(i) = max(1<=k<=floor(i/2)) {B(k) + B(i-k)} and P(i)

Formula 2: B(i) = max(1<=k<=i) {p(k) + B(i-k)})

Consider a rod of length 4,
it can be cut in the following ways :

1) uncut of length 4

2) 3, 1

3) 2, 2

4) 2, 1, 1

5) 1, 3

6) 1, 2, 1

7) 1, 1, 2

8) 1, 1, 1, 1

According to Formula 1:

option 1 corresponds to P(4)

option 2,5,6,7,8 corresponds to B(1) + B(3)

option 3,4,6,7,8 corresponds to B(2) + B(2)

According to Formula 2:

option 1 corresponds to  P(4)

option 2 corresponds to  P(3) + B(1)

option 3,4 corresponds to P(2) + B(2)

option 5,6,7,8 corresponds to P(1) + B(3)

So to conclude, 1 and 2 are counting the optimal solution but in different ways, where 2 is more compact and makes lesser recursive calls compared to 1.

Comment: Thankss U made me understandd, and thanks for the question posted too